# Concatenate columns and create a list

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to concatenate a couple of columns that result in either a list of strings or a list of ints.

I've done this so far;

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6],'C':[7,8,9]})

data1['D'] = [' '.join(str(row)) for row in data1[data1.columns[0:3]].values] # add a new column by concatenating the existing columns

   A  B  C              D
0  1  4  7  [ 1   4   7 ]
1  2  5  8  [ 2   5   8 ]
2  3  6  9  [ 3   6   9 ]
```

How do I get the string `'[1 4 7]'` converted as a list of strings like `['1','4','7']` or a list of ints like `[1,4,7]` ?

Comment: There a few errors in your code, should be `data1[data1.columns[0:3]].values]` ranges are open closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use `join`:

```
data1['E'] = [row for row in data1[data1.columns[0:3]].values]
```

Comment: Gosh! It was that simple. What was I doing! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using a regular expression: (can be easily modified to extract negative floats...)

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('(\d+)', '[1 4 7]')
['1', '4', '7']
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to concatenate them to strings if it is not necessary.

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6],'C':[7,8,9]})
longs = data1.iloc[0].tolist()
```

`iloc[0]` selects the first item of the DataFrame, and `tolist()` converts it to a list. You get a list of numbers of type `long`.

Then use this to convert the lists values to `int`:

```
ints = [int(x) for x in longs]
```

Long story short:

```
ints = [int(x) for x in data1.iloc[0].tolist()]
```

Comment: I get the output as `[1L, 4L, 7L]`. Why is that? how do I handle them?

Comment: These are numbers of type `long`. You can work with them, but to get `int` values, please see my edit.